# Is it bad practice to have PHP conditional statements directly called from the index file (mixed with HTML markup)?

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

Some people have told me that the following code is bad for HTML validation:

**index.php:**

line 1 ~ 5 (this one is OK. Just for reference):

```
<?php include_once 'localization.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
```

line 15 (if Chinese is selected load those CSS files):

```
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-tw.php' || $lang_file=='lang.zh-cn.php') 
{echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/chinese.css" />';} ?>
```

line 21 (if English is the current language change assign to it the class: current):

```
<li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.en.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>>
<a href="index.php?lang=en">ENGLISH</a></li>
```

line 168 ~ 171 (this is the only way I found to add different languages to the jquery validation plugin):

```
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.en.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-en.js"></script>';} ?>
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.es.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-es.js"></script>';} ?>
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-tw.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-zh-tw.js"></script>';} ?>
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-cn.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-zh-cn.js"></script>';} ?>
```

lozalization.php (for reference only):

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];

    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else {
    $lang = 'en';
}

// use appropiate lang.xx.php file according to the value of the $lang
$languages = array('en', 'es', 'zh-tw', 'zh-cn');
if (in_array($_SESSION['lang'], $languages)) {
    $lang_file = 'lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php';
} else {
    $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
}

//localization helper function
function l($localization) {
    global $lang;
    return $lang[$localization];
}
    include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

I am falling into bad practices or validation problems? The code works, but is there's a way of doing the things above in a cleaner and better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP statements in your index file are **not** bad for HTML validation, assuming they generate valid HTML. If you check the source of the page in a web-browser, you'll see that all your PHP tags are gone and replaced with whatever they were there to produce. This is what gets validated.

With regards to making things cleaner, you might try replacing

```
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.en.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-en.js"></script>';} ?>
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.es.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-es.js"></script>';} ?>
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-tw.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-zh-tw.js"></script>';} ?>
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-cn.php') {echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-zh-cn.js"></script>';} ?>
```

with something like

```
<?php
$lang = explode('.',$lang_file);
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-validate/val-'.$lang[1].'.js"></script>' ?>
```

That way, assuming the variable translation between `$lang_file` and the validation script are always along the lines of lang.**en**.php to val-**en**.js, this will support any languages you care to throw at it without requiring a line of code each. Obviously if $lang_file can be manipulated by the user you'll want to make sure it contains what you expect it to contain.

Comment: I worked perfectly thanks. One more thing, why did you include that explode thing?

Comment: Don't run the code! He's trying to blow up your server! J/k:

http://us3.php.net/explode

BTW, install the PHP.net search tool for Firefox. That way you can easily look up php functions.

Comment: @Lèse majesté Ha you scared me because I didn't know the meaning of j/k.

Comment: explode turns the string into an array, breaking it up along the argument, in this case '.' - Effectively, what we need is the part of $lang_file between the first two dots. So, first we break it into an array, and then select the second element (index 1)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak specifically for bad practices, but in terms of loading the correct jquery script, just do a substring match on the contents of $lang_file, then concatenate it onto the end of the directory holding all of the scripts. That way, you can add/remove locales without having to change your script.